# how to test behavior that depends on a package being installed or not

Tags: r, testthat

I have a function like this:

```
func <- function(x) {
  if (requireNamespace("broom", quietly = TRUE)) {

    print(1)

  } else {

    print(2)

  }
```

I'd like to write tests using `testthat` that trigger *both* cases. But of course `broom` either is or isn't installed on my computer.  What to do?

Comment: have a look at installed.packages()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit**: this no longer works as of `testthat-2.0.0`. According to a [change in Oct 2017](https://github.com/r-lib/testthat/blob/252514e70b229d0a6c58cb44d7f605c852b6a10c/NEWS.md):

> - "Can't mock functions in base packages": You can no longer use `with_mock()` to mock functions in base packages, because this no longer works in R-devel due to changes with the byte code compiler. I recommend using [mockery](https://github.com/n-s-f/mockery) or [mockr](https://github.com/krlmlr/mockr) instead.

Rest of the answer only applies to older versions of `testthat`.

---

`testthat::with_mock` should do what you want.

```
library(testthat)
somefunc <- function() if (requireNamespace("base", quietly=TRUE)) 1L else 2L
```

Some simple tests:

```
expect_equal( somefunc(), 1L )
```

Successful.

```
expect_equal( somefunc(), 2L )
# Error: somefunc() not equal to 2.
# 1/1 mismatches
# [1] 1 - 2 == -1
```

Expected.

Let's create a "mock" function that overrides the base function:

```
with_mock(
  `base::requireNamespace` = function(package, ..., quietly=FALSE) FALSE,
  expect_equal( somefunc(), 1L )
)
# Error: somefunc() not equal to 1.
# 1/1 mismatches
# [1] 2 - 1 == 1

with_mock(
  `base::requireNamespace` = function(package, ..., quietly=FALSE) FALSE,
  expect_equal( somefunc(), 2L )
)
# [1] 2
```

Note: on success, `expect_equal` invisibly returns the return value, so you don't see `[1] 1` in the first example. `with_mock`, on success, returns the return value but not invisibly. In both cases, failure will return a modified return value. This minute difference should not affect any tests.

Depending on the function you are overriding, it makes sense (to me) to be careful to define the mock function with identical formals. You might be able to shortcut this if you know *exactly* how it is *always* called in *all* subordinate functions during your tests, but I think the extra careful attention to the formals will preclude really hard-to-troubleshoot test failures.

NB: the help states that this

> *... is still experimental, so use with care*.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer is valid any longer... I'm getting an error "Error: Can't mock functions in base packages (base)"

Comment: Thanks @MichaelChirico, I've updated the question to reflect it.

Comment: Thanks. FWIW I kludged it quickly in my own tests by doing `requireNamespace = function(...) FALSE; my_test; rm(requireNamespace)`... I guess this will do the trick for the most part

Comment: That works as long as the testing is done only in your code ... if a dependent package is calling it, I suspect the search path would use `base` before your version, so it might require the use of the other packages (though I've not tested). Thanks again, it's good to keep these answers current.

Comment: HTH. Your point about the pitfalls of the kludge are well taken!

Answer (score 0):

```
    old_fn <- base::requireNamespace
    myrequireNamespace <- function(...) FALSE
    unlockBinding("requireNamespace", as.environment("package:base"))
    assign("requireNamespace",myrequireNamespace, "package:base")
    expect_error(read_data("meta",data_table,  frame=NULL),"Package \"readxl\" 
    needed for this function to load excel files")
    assign("requireNamespace",old_fn, "package:base")
    lockBinding("requireNamespace", as.environment("package:base"))
    rm(old_fn, myrequireNamespace)
```

is a work-around for me that does work inside of testthat.